# JSON string gets truncated in apache flink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using kafka as my source in apache flink. My kafka producer is sending a big json string, but it is getting truncated to 4095 characters and my json parsing fails. I have no control over size of json string, can you please explain and help me tackle this issue?

Code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import models._
import org.apache.flink.types.Row
import net.liftweb.json._

case class ParsedPage(data: String, domain:String, url:String, text: String)

object HelloWorld{
  def main(args:Array[String]){

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
    val kafkaConsumer011 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String]("first_topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
    val stream: DataStream[String] = env.addSource[String](kafkaConsumer011);
    val result: DataStream[Row] = stream.filter(_.nonEmpty).flatMap{ p =>
      try {
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
        Seq(parse(p).extract[ParsedPage])
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          println(s"Parsing failed for message in txn: $p")
          Seq()
      }}.map { p =>
      val bookJson = ""
      val cityId = ""
      Row.of(voyagerId, cityId)
    }
    stream.print()
    env.execute()
  }
}
```

Flink Version : 1.4.2
Scala Version: 2.11.8

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger and set a breakpoint in the `flatMap`? Is the string already truncated? Did you check the Kafka message size limit?

Comment: @twalthr yeah, The issue was with my kafka producer. While running kafka producer from my console, it truncates my string. I tried the same from python code, created a producer there, and send the string and it didn't get truncated. Thanks

Comment: @anonymous post your answer as a solutions and close the answer pls